# Theming for ladybug

Tags: symfony

What name do I have to use in the `ladybug_set_theme()` command to set the theme that has been used in the [screenshot](https://github.com/raulfraile/ladybug/raw/master/doc/images/int_modern.png) in the [documentation](https://github.com/raulfraile/ladybug/blob/master/doc/usage.md)?

How can I set the theme and format for my entire application? (avoiding calls to `ladybug_set_theme()` and `ladybug_set_format()`in each controller/method)

What themes are available in general?

UPDATE:

I had done the install via composer using

```
"raulfraile/ladybug": "~1.0"
```

Composer installed both the latest version and the modern theme:

```
- Installing raulfraile/ladybug-theme-modern (v1.0.7)
  Downloading: 100%

- Installing raulfraile/ladybug (v1.0.11)
  Downloading: 100%
```

I then also ran the following as suggested by FyodorX:

```
λ php app/console assets:install
Installing assets as hard copies
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for Sonata\CoreBundle into web/bundles/sonatacore
Installing assets for Sonata\jQueryBundle into web/bundles/sonatajquery
Installing assets for Sonata\AdminBundle into web/bundles/sonataadmin
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
```

I also cleared the cache. This did not have any effect.

The theme is activated, however, when I call `ladybug_set_theme("modern");` before the `ldd()` command. (I had only tried `ladybug_set_theme("classic");` before, as is [suggested in the docs](https://github.com/raulfraile/ladybug/blob/master/doc/usage.md#configuration).)

**With the problem of getting the theme to be applied solved, can anyone suggest a way to set the theme once for the entire application?**

I am assuming that otherwise, I will have to make a call to `ladybug_set_theme()` on every use. (correct assumption?)

Comment: That's the default theme and it's called `modern`. How did you install the bundle? In case you used `composer`, can you provide the require line you're using?

Comment: Got it working now as described in my update to the original post. Can you suggest a way to set the theme globally?

Comment: Which environment are you on? Try changing to another and see if it works properly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme you see in the documentation is the default theme and it's called `modern`.

Make sure you add the right dependency for Symfony2...:

```
{
    "require": {
        "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

... and enable the bundle:

```
<?php
// app/AppKernel.php

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new RaulFraile\Bundle\LadybugBundle\RaulFraileLadybugBundle(),
    );
}
```

Try reinstalling the assets and clearing the cache, too:

```
$ php app/console assets:install
$ rm -fr .cache/*
```

You can change the theme programmatically using `ladybug_set_theme()`, but you shouldn't have to since `modern` is the default theme.

Comment: I did not have an entry in AppKernel thus far. (The documentation is not mentioning any.)

Unfortunately, the bundle you recommended including (`new RaulFraile\Bundle\LadybugBundle\RaulFraileLadybugBundle(),`) is not recognized.

The only occurrences of the word "Bundle" I can find in the vendor directory are in README files.

Comment: I've expanded my answer. You've probably installed the `raulfraile/ladybug` package. You want `raulfraile/ladybug-bundle` instead, which is the Symfony2-ready version of `ladybug`.

Comment: Spot on. Switched to the 'ladybug-bundle' package as suggested and everything works as desired now.